# Contrast Self attention and Attention in machine learning for non technical person?

Tags: machine-learning, transformers, attention

How would you contrast Self attention and Attention in machine learning for a non technical person?

I really like this explanation of Attention from Chatgpt: When someone speaks to you, you naturally focus your "attention" on that person's voice, ignoring the others for a moment. In the same way, in a computer, "attention" is like a spotlight that helps it focus on the most important parts of information while ignoring the less important stuff. This makes it easier for the computer to understand and process the things it needs to, just like you do when you're listening to someone in a noisy room.

However, the one for self attention is not that intuitive.